# Adding css property in html tag

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am looking for a work around to add some css styling into my html tag. I do not want to edit the css file because I am using the particular formatting only once.

This is what I have tried and did not work out. I think the format is not being overridden by the css file.

```
<p margin-right ="3px" class="nav navbar-text navbar-right">Signed in as: @User.Identity.Name!</p>
```

How can I get it right?

Comment: You could do `<p style="margin-right: 3px" ...`, but you should avoid inline styles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's better to have it on a style.css file but it's like this:

```
<p style="margin-right:3px;" class="nav navbar-text navbar-right">
```

Comment: Is it a good idea to edit the Bootstrap css file? i am not having a custom css file.

Comment: Please, NEVER edit the bootstrap.css, because if you have to download a new version of bootstrap, it will erase all the css you've done.

Comment: Even if I have only a single custom styling i should make a new css file right?

Comment: At least, do at the end of your php/html file:
<style type="text/css">
//ALL YOUR CSS HERE
</style>

Comment: Yes you should make a new css file, that's the best solution.

Comment: you can also use internal css. i.e., using <style> tag

Comment: OK. So if i want to add the above in style. I should add 

`#navbar-right {margin-right :3px}

Comment: No, "#" is for id, here you have a class, you should add '.navbar-right {margin-right:3px}'

Comment: I tried adding the style in my HTML page. But it doesnt give the same output as the inline styling.

`<style type="text/css">
        .navbar-right {
            margin-right: -200px;
        }
    </style>`

Comment: I think that you have other elements with class = navbar-right.
To add only to one element, use the ID. Add to your html <p id="MyModification">
And in your css #MyModification { margin-right:-200px }

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this -

```
<p style="margin-right:3px" class="nav navbar-text navbar-right">
    Signed in as: @User.Identity.Name!
</p>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can create style at top i.e.

```
<style type='text/css'>
.mr3p {
    margin-right: 3px !important;
}
</style>

<p class="nav navbar-text navbar-right mr3p">
```

Comment: is it necessary that i add `!important`

Comment: Yes when you want to override some style then you need to apply !important.

Comment: Please, try not to use !important, it's always better to search from where is your problem than putting a !important.

Comment: Dont use !important - its **evil**. Let the styles cascade and use the appropriate scoping of selectors. !important should be reserved for emergencies (i.e. working with code where you cannot affect the emitted CSS)